# Getting null values from shared object using rtmp client library in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, red5, rtmp

I am trying simple android application that connects to the red5 server and sends video stream, connect to other clients that are connected to red5 server.
One way to discover other clients is by creating shared objects.
In my code using `IClientSharedObject` i created a shared object like follows

```
sharedobj = rtmpclient.getSharedObject("so", true);
```

then try to set some attributes by using `setAttribute()` method like

```
sharedobj.beginUpdate();
sharedobj.setAttribute("object1",object);
sharedobj.endUpdate();
```

Now when i tried to get data after this using `sharedobj.getData()` or `sharedobj.getAttribute("object1")` it gives null values.
Is this issue because the attribute is not set, becuase i can see in the logs that shared object is created
My rtmp client librarby version is 0.3 downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/)

Any clue what the problem is ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get answer?